# How to navigate from custom navigator to createBottomTabNavigator in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I've a custom navigator because I wanted to go back to the previous screen using a back swipe gesture. Below is the code of the main file from where the navigators are called.

```
const MainSwipeStack = () => {
    return(
        <Navigator>
            <Route name="LoggedOutHome" component={LoggedOutHome} />
            <Route name="SignUp" component={SignUp} />
            <Route name="SignupUsername" component={SignupUsername} />
            <Route name="Login" component={Login} /> 
        </Navigator> 
    );
}

export default createSwitchNavigator({
    SwipeStack: {screen: MainSwipeStack},
    TabHolder: {screen: TabHolder}
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'SwipeStack',
    headerMode: 'none',
});
```

And below is the link to the `Navigator.js` code. (I didn't add the code here because it's a long code.)

https://gist.github.com/shubham6996/a4197d2d0b664d4aabe01091cac6c91e

And the `TabHolder` takes me to the screen which has `createBottomTabNavigator`.

So, now I'm not able to navigate from the `Login` screen to `TabHolder` stack.

How can I navigate from `Login` which is in a custom navigator to `TabHolder` stack?

Comment: how you are calling TabHolder Screen in Login?

Comment: @JaydeepGalani I tried using `this.props.navigation.navigate(`TabHolder');` but this isn't working.

Comment: you can not directly use Login because it is nested inside SwipeStack. Use this `this.props.navigation.navigate(SwipeStack');` and do something in that stack to make Login screen appear first instead of LoggedOutHome.

Comment: @JaydeepGalani sorry, you misunderstood my problem. I want to go from `Login` to `TabHolder`

Comment: Oops sorry about that, so what is the error?

Comment: `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.navigate')`

Comment: seems navigation props is not there , try this `export default withNavigation(Login);` in login and yes do import also  `import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation'`

Comment: @JaydeepGalani yes it worked! Thank you so much! But can you please explain why using `withNavigation` worked here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems navigation props is not there,

try this

```
export default withNavigation(Login);
```

in login and yes do import also

```
import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation'
```

Components which are not directly used in navigators do not have navigation prop by default.

So you need to either pass it as normal props like this,

```
<Login navigation={this.props.navigation}
```

but in stack we dont have navigation prop so we can not pass like this (or idk if we have prop there....)

so alternate option is `withNavigation` and `withNaviagtionFocus` as shown above

find details about [withNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html)