# React Navigation - Navigation options with nested navigators

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Im still learning React Native. I kinda know how React Navigation works. Now Im getting a little bit stuck with Navigation Nesting. Im gonna try to be quick.

First, whats the practical way to nest navigators?

I was doing it somehow using nesting, but came across with a problem. Im only able to change navigation options in the nested navigator not in the component screen. I have difficulties opening the drawer menu from one of the screens since Im using a custom header plus using nested navigators. I have a similar code Im using for testing:

App.js (Navigators)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createDrawerNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import SplashScreen from './SplashScreen';
import MainScreen from './MainScreen';
import FirstTabScreen from './FirstTabScreen';
import SecondTabScreen from './SecondTabScreen';

const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    splash: {
        screen: SplashScreen
    },
    mainFlow: {
        screen: createDrawerNavigator({
            main: {
                screen: MainScreen
            },
            someTab: {
                screen: createBottomTabNavigator({
                    firstTab: {
                        screen: FirstTabScreen
                    },
                    secondTab: {
                        screen: SecondTabScreen
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppStackNavigator);


export default class App extends Component{

    render(){
        return <AppContainer/>;
    }
}
```

Above code will launch SplashScreen which is good and has the following:

SplashScreen.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';

export default class SplashScreen extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null
    }

    go = () =>{
        this.props.navigation.navigate('main');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Button title='GO NEXT SCREEN' onPress={this.go}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

In this screen navigation options work in the same code and its as expected. Everything cool for now, when I press the button and go to the next screen which is MainScreen:

MainScreen.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, Button, View } from 'react-native';

export default class MainScreen extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null
    }

    drawer = () => {
        this.props.navigation.openDrawer();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.baseText}>HELLO</Text>
                <Button title='DRAWER' onPress={this.drawer}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    baseText: {
        fontFamily: 'Cochin',
    },
    titleText: {
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
});
```

Here is the problem, navigation options wont work here, so I was trying setting those lines in the navigator itself and it works if I configure header as null but if I want to control 'props.navigation' it will say 'this.props.navigation' is undefined.

So, ideal question would be, is there a way to make navigation options available from the screen component itself? somehow? or is there a way I can put this navigation options inside the navigator with working navigation props that wont say its undefined?

All this is because I want to customize my header

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use withNavigation to provide navigation prop there,

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000378/how-to-navigate-from-custom-navigator-to-createbottomtabnavigator-in-react-nativ/55017214#55017214)

Comment: This is the answer. Just in case, somebody comes across with the same problem. I wrote navigation options inside the navigator code. I created a custom headerLeft button and inside its code I wrote a 'export default withNavigation'. Now, when you call the custom button from the headerLeft property it will use properly the navigation props.

Answer (score 1):

In `SplashScreen.js` you are not navigating to the right screen

you have to do

```
go = () =>{
        this.props.navigation.navigate('mainFlow');
    }
```